.NET 8 Azure Functions Container CORS
I just containerized a .NET 8 Azure Functions app. It works, but I can't make CORS work.
// Program.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using APIs.Services.Azure.Storage.Queue;
using APIs.Services.Cache;
using APIs.Services.DocumentDB.Repositories;
using APIs.Services.MongoDB.Repositories;
using APIs.Services.User;
using APIs.Services.Logzio;
using APIs.Services.IPFS;
using APIs.Services.Midjourney;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {

        IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;

        services.AddSingleton<ICachingService, CachingService>();
        // I also add other services here

        // CORS
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5000); // Change to the desired port
        })
        .Configure((context, app) =>
        {
            // Use the CORS policy
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

and
//host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0,
      "maxDequeueCount": 1
    },
    "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 1,
    "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 1
  },
  "http": {
    "routePrefix": "",
    "cors": {
      "allowedOrigins": [
        "*"
      ],
      "allowedMethods": [
        "*"
      ],
      "allowedHeaders": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}

Then I build the image and create the container.
If I go to the app url, I can see the Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running message.
But when I'm trying to use the API from my frontend app, I get CORS error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://host.docker.internal:7171/api/wallet' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


please check if the solution below helps you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Did you try adding origin URL in API >> CORS setting of your azure function as below?
CORS Settings MSDN

AllowAnyOrigin() and AllowCredentials() cannot be used together.
To resolve the issue with CORS, remove AllowCredentials() in your code.
 builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                });

If you want AllowCredentials() and AllowAnyOrigin() together, you can use SetIsOriginAllowed(origin=>true) as mentioned in SO answer by @Konstantin Nikolskii.
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});


Use below code to allow access to the specific origin:

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("withorigin",builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("https://example.com")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
});


I have created a .NET8.0 Isolated Azure function and enabled CORS with below code:
Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
         services.AddCors(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
         builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowCredentials());
     });
})
    .Build();

host.Run();

Deployed to Azure:


